# How to force user to swipe twice home indicator to go home-screen?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using react-native. I'm programming an app that needs a lot of swipe function. Always when it hits the home indicator, it close the app. What I want to do is, that the user should force to swipe twice to go to the home-screen. Example: Clash of Clans, Clash Royal and other Games

I couldn't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in react native core. However, you can try using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-home-pressed) package. It handles the android home and recent buttons.

Swiping to close using the home button is not recommended. The people will get stuck in your app and that leads to bad UX, since the user expects to go Home when they press home.

Instead i would suggest to handle the back button since that's the main navigation button.